# web api in an external assembly under asp.net application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have a set of web APIs which contained inside a web application.

I'm trying to separate them into a new dll under the publishing folder of the web app.

After the separation and with the following routing code the individual api calling is successful.

But I need the initialization code like Ninject initialization and routing register that are originally inside of Application_Start() of the web application to be put inside of the new dll. How can I do that so that the relevant code could be called before the first api invoke?

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
name: "DefaultApi",
routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it will be not a problem at all with routing registered in external assebmly and some nInject code also.

But troubles could be when your controllers are in external assembly. Please read about it in details here:
http://www.strathweb.com/2012/06/using-controllers-from-an-external-assembly-in-asp-net-web-api/

Putting your controllers in a separate assembly is very straight forward.  You just need to update your route registrations to tell them where to look for the controllers.

```
routes.MapRoute(name: "Default", url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                namespaces: new[] {"[Namespace of the Project that contains your controllers]"},
                defaults: new {controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional});
```

Comment: but where/how should i call the initialization stuff now inside a dll before the first api gets called, things like ninject initialization...that were originally called inside application_start inside the web app

Comment: You can call initialization stuff inside global.asax or outside. Anyway when you are creating any external initialization logic you should call it from Application_Start from Global.asax, means logic can be outside but e.g. routing should be initialized there